# Filtering JSONPath with given string value

Tags: json, jsonpath

If I have a JSON like so:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
        "service" : { "id" : 1 }
    },
    {
        "service" : { "id" : 2 }
    },
    {
        "service" : {}
    }
  ]
}
```

This query works:

```
$..service[?(@.id==2)]
```

And gives expected result:

```
[
    {
        "id" : 2
    }
]
```

However, if I had strings as id's:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
        "service" : { "id" : "a" }
    },
    {
        "service" : { "id" : "b" }
    },
    {
        "service" : {}
    }
  ]
}
```

Running similar query:

```
$..service[?(@.id == "a")]
```

Gives no results (empty array).
I am using [this evaluator](http://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/).
I was looking at docs [here](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) but could not find anything to point me in the right direction... Any help if someone knows how to write such query? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without " works

```
$..service[?(@.id == b)]
```

give this result

```
[
   {
      "id" : "b"
   }
]
```